# Is it possible to wrap a classic exe inside a .net dll?

Tags: asp.net

I think Shared asp.net hosting accepts to run dll not exe so is it possible to wrap somehow a classic exe inside a .net dll ?

Answer (score 1):

The classic or unmanaged .exe will require a process space in which to run. If you want to run the code inside it inside the process space of another, you'll have to reload the exe's code into your process space manually - I suspect this is doable, but not easy. It would be far easier if the unmanaged exe code was in an unmanaged dll. Then you could just P/Invoke it. However your application will need to be running at high privilege and thus the shared  hosting provider will need to make those right available to your application.